# Retrieving randomically values in a dictionary with specific conditions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, random

I want to extract one key out of my dictionary where the value is >= 0.05. My dictionary looks like this

```
{'Bed_to_Toilet': 0.5645161290322581, 
'Sleep': 0.016129032258064516, 
'Morning_Meds': 0.03225806451612903, 
'Watch_TV': 0.0, 
'Kitchen_Activity': 0.04838709677419355, 
'Chores': 0.0, 
'Leave_Home': 0.03225806451612903, 
'Read': 0.0, 
'Guest_Bathroom': 0.08064516129032258, 
'Master_Bathroom': 0.22580645161290322}
```

and I want `startActivity` to be a random name from these keys, like the first time I run my code is `startActivity = Bed_to_Toilet`, the second time is `startActivity = Guest_Bathroom` and so on.
How can I do it?

I tried doing this

```
def findFirstActivity(self, startActModel):
   startActivity, freq = random.choice(list(startActModel.items()))
   return startActivity
```

and it works pretty well, I just need a way to add for a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st, get a list of reference keys that match your criteria:

```
candidate_list = [k for k,v in startActModel.items() if v >= 0.05]
```

Then you can `random.choice` from that list:

```
mykey = random.choice(candidate_list)
```

At which point, if wanted, you can go back and access the value chosen:

```
myval = startActModel[mykey]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your API unchanged.
You can pass to `findFirstActivity()` a filtered version of your dict.
Thanks to a dict comprehension.

```py
filtered_startActModel = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if v >= 0.05}
```